# Casas decimais em DGV em C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Segue 2 imagens que resumem meu problema.

Imagem do db (Access)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem do DataGridView

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando lançado os valores com casas decimais "0" o DGV não mostra, Ex:
1.00 = 1
1.50 = 1.5

Segue as propriedades do campo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma forma de levar os valores completos ao DGV ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema com os seguintes codigos !

```
     NomedoDataGrid.Columns[Numero ou Nome da Coluna].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"
```

*valores monetarios com duas casas decimais*

```
     NomedoDataGrid.Columns[Numero ou Nome da Coluna].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
```

*valores numericos com duas casas decimais*

```
     NomedoDataGrid.Columns[Numero ou Nome da Coluna].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d"
```

*formato para data*

Abraços !

Comment: Boa tarde amigo, em qual parte voce inseriu estes codigos ??